# Export iMovie 09/10 Project to Theora with 720p resolution

Tags: export, ogg, video-conversion, imovie, theora

I select "export with QuickTime"

Choose - OGG

"Xiph Theora" is selected as codec. Actually, it's alone in the list of codecs. That's what i need.

I can adjust quality, FPS ... but resolution selection is not presented.

I always get 960x540, but need 720p.

From UI there is no way to select resolution.

I'm sure, that resolution is presented somewhere (otherwise, how iMovie knows it?)

The only option, i found in ...

```
Library/Preferences/com.apple.iMovieApp.plist
```

... is "exportMovieSize", which equals to 4. Changing to 5 does't takes any effect.

Maybe i need to tweak something else ?